# QKeySequence 'CTRL + PLUS' shortcut doesn't work for german keyboard layout

Tags: qt, qt5.5, qkeyevent, qkeysequence

I'm new to Qt and advanced Programming. In my project, I have a `QKeySequence` shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>PLUS</kbd> & <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>MINUS</kbd> keys. They work fine in numerical <kbd>PLUS</kbd> & <kbd>MINUS</kbd> Keys but, they don't trigger required action if used in OEM PLUS & MINUS Keys for German and Italian keyboard layout. I tested them in a simple program with `KeyPressEvent()` to print debug message, still it did not trigger the action. I used `nativeVirtualKey()` and I was able to print the debug message. I used Qt 5.5.0 and 5.5.1 and test them using windows onscreen keyboard. Is there anyway to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> shortcut in `QKeySequence` for keyboards without numerical keys.

Another observation in same issue is faced in Qt Creator. The <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>PLUS</kbd> shortcut to increase font size does not work in German keyboard and for the Danish keyboard it's the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>MINUS</kbd> that does not work.

`QKeySequnce`:

```
const QKeySequence g_markerIncrease = QKeySequence(CTRL + Key_Plus);
```

This is how I used `nativevirtualkey()`:

```
if ( event->nativeVirtualKey() == 187 ) //virtualkeycode for Non numeric PLUS
{
    qDebug() << "message";
}
```

Edit 1:
187 is the integer value of VirtualKey hex value in [VK List](http://kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html) as per [suggestion in Qt centre forum](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/41552-CTRL-in-keyPressEvent?highlight=german+keyboard)

Comment: @Azeem thanks for the edit

Comment: You are welcome! What is `187`? Did you try this with latest Qt versions?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qkeysequence.html#keyboard-layout-issues

Comment: I tried in Qt 5.5.0 and 5.5.1 and 5.11.1 but still the issue persisted. Regarding value 187 I added a edit.I Checked the layout issues ,there must be someway to solve this issue (Note: in  Qt creator shortcut for 5.5.1  CTRL + PLUS worked fine for increasing font size in german keyboard.). Now I'm working on finding the solution with QKeyEvent(). Though knowing how to handle this issue in QkeySequence would help in future avoid the focus issues in qKeyEvent

Comment: Right. You should report a bug also to get a quick response from Qt team.